# save a xml file with c# in Universal app

Tags: c#, xml, windows-10-universal

I've this Xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<GirlsTimes>
  <Angie>00:00:00</Angie>
  ...
  <Nicole>00:00:00</Nicole>
</GirlsTimes>
```

I've a textbox when you can put a time in format "hh:mm:ss" (TBAngie).
When the focus on this textbox was lost, I want to save the new value in the same Xml file :

```
private async void TBAngie_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!checkContent(TBAngie.Text))
        {
            TBAngie.Text = string.Empty;
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("Veuillez encodez un temps hh:mm:ss svp.");
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
            xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            xws.Indent = true;

            using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xws))
            {
                string repMaxXMLPath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "XML/GirlsTimes.xml");
                loadedData = XDocument.Load(repMaxXMLPath);
                var items = from item in loadedData.Descendants("GirlsTimes")
                            where item.Element("Angie").Value != TBAngie.Text
                            select item;

                foreach (XElement itemElement in items)
                {
                    itemElement.SetElementValue("Angie", TBAngie.Text);
                }

                loadedData.Save(xw);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var dialog = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Apparently the `<Angie>` node value was update well (I see the updated node in debug mode), but when I refresh the page (quit the current page and reload it), the value was not update. So I think my method to save the new xml was not good but I don't know why...

What I made wrong ? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Just before `loadedData.Save()` I've made a .toString() and I've this :

```
<GirlsTimes>
  <Angie>00:12:34</Angie>
   ...
  <Nicole>00:00:00</Nicole>
</GirlsTimes>
```

Comment: Make sure items has at least one row.

Comment: Print out the `loadedData.ToString()` before you call Save. What do you see there?

Comment: @Nox Noctis, I've made an edit. The xml was updated well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app's install directory is a read-only location. If you need to change file contents, copy it to `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`. So, when your app loads the file, try the `LocalFolder` location first, if no file is there, read it from `InstalledLocation`.

Refer to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) for details.

Comment: I'll try this ;) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wouaouhhh, after many searchs and try, I've the solution :

This is my read method (I Know isn't the right way to use try/catch/finally...)) :

```
        private async void GetGirlsTimes()
        {
            StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            try
            {
                StorageFile textFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("GirlsTimes.xml");
                using (IRandomAccessStream textStream = await textFile.OpenReadAsync())
                {
                    Stream s = textStream.AsStreamForRead();
                    loadedData = XDocument.Load(s);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                storageFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("AppData");
                storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("GirlsTimes.xml");
                using (IRandomAccessStream writeStream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
                {
                    Stream s = writeStream.AsStreamForRead();
                    loadedData = XDocument.Load(s);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
               ...//put the value from loadedData to my differents TextBoxes.
            }
        }
```

And this is My Write Method :

```
 var items = from item in loadedData.Descendants("GirlsTimes")
                                where item.Element("Angie").Name == "Angie"
                                select item;

                    foreach (XElement itemElement in items)
                    {
                        itemElement.SetElementValue("Angie", TBAngie.Text);
                    }

                    StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                    StorageFile textFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("GirlsTimes.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                    using (IRandomAccessStream textStream = await textFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        using (DataWriter textWriter = new DataWriter(textStream))
                        {
                            textWriter.WriteString(loadedData.ToString());
                            await textWriter.StoreAsync();
                        }
                    }
```

And then I can write/read/update my Xml. Thanks For the help. I Valid Your Answer Nox Noctis :)

Comment: I don't know about win 10 uwp yet, but in 8.1 store projects there is no other way of checking if a file exists, except for trying to open it and catching the FileNotFountException.

Comment: I have found nothing better works yet for w10... maybe with the update there will be better :)

Comment: System.IO.File.Exists(path) should work in uwp.
E.g.: if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, GirlsTimes.xml))
{
 //TODO: The file exists
}